# browser.getAllWindowHandles() is throwing an error saying it is not a function

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I am trying to switch between tabs using protractor, below is the command used

```
browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
    browser.switchTo().window(handles[0]);
});
```

It is throwing an error saying browser.getAllWindowHandles is not a function

Can anyone help me with this, using protractor how can I get the total tabs count open and switch between the tabs

Comment: Can you add the error stack trace,

Comment: Check your code to see you assign other value to the `browser`,

Comment: this worked when i used browser.driver.getAllWindowHandles()

Answer (score 0):

if browser.getAllWindowHandles() is not working then try with browser.driver.getAllWindowHandles() and make sure you give some wait for till the second tab is completely loaded.

this worked for me